# Принцип работы exception php

Tags: php, mysqli, исключения

`mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
...

```
try {
      $result = $this->link->real_escape_string(
        $this->link->query($query)
      );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      Service::error($e);
    }
    return $result;
```

// вариант выше точно должен работать. Будет ли работать вариант ниже? Если да, прокомментируйте это как-то.. Не очень понятен принцип срабатывания exception

```
try {
      return $this->link->real_escape_string(
        $this->link->query($query)
      );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      Service::error($e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Принцип срабатывания Exception достаточно простой:

```
<?php

try {
    $flag = true;
    $i = 0;
    do {
        $n = rand(0,10);
        if ($n>4) {
            throw new Exception('Ошибка на итерации: '.$i, 999);
        }
        $i++;
    }
    while ($flag);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Ошибочка #'.$e->getCode().': '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

Когда нужно выбрасываете *Exception* , а в **catch** ловите то, что выбросили.

Подробнее бы вам советовал поискать в гугле по словосочетанию "php exception". Тут есть на эту тему https://habrahabr.ru/post/264417/ .

Comment: обрати внимание на то, что в примере не все так просто как кажется. Там как бы кидаются исключения средствами mysql. Или...?

Comment: да любыми средствами... для начала нужно определиться, какого типа исключения (возможно просто ошибки), а затем ловить их.